# yGuard now issues a warning if the package or class or method name of a native method is obfuscated

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, native, yguard

I am getting these errors due to java native method in yguard:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Sorry ..!its company policy I can not share the code.but due to java native method I am getting those all kind of error. I found in "yGuard now issues a warning if the package or class or method name of a native method is obfuscated." in yguard web site.if possible please help me..!

Comment: Can you give an *example* of code that would cause the problem then?

Comment: class Happy
    {
    public native void printText ();
    static
   {
   System.loadLibrary ("happy");   
   }
    public static void main (String[] args)
   {
   Happy happy = new Happy ();
   happy.printText ();
   }
    }